# Как можно реализовать качение картинки на подобие дерева на ветру

Tags: css3, jquery, css

С помощью чего или возможно есть примеры, пытался реализовать на `CSS3` не получилось. Картинка прозрачная, `png` лежит над общим дизайном сайта.

Comment: а гиф вам чем не угодил? css для простых анимаций создан. он не будет вам изображение искажать

Comment: @galloko, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: PNG, gif тут не поможет.

Comment: возможно все же jQuery мне поможет а не css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему не будет?

```
<head>
<style> 
div#tree_1
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:anim_1 5s infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation:anim_1 5s infinite alternate; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes anim_1
{
from {transform: skew(30deg);}
to {transform: skew(40deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim_1 /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {transform: skew(30deg);}
to {transform: skew(40deg);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tree_1"></div>

</body>
```

И таких дивов с картинками делаете штук 10 по всей длине изображения, составляя что-то типа рисунка на жалюзях. Кроме skew вам может еще понадобится transition чтобы выравнивать края.

Но это изврат, да. Юзайте JS и Canvas

Comment: Прощай ИЕ и страрый опера,

Прощай,

И Фаерфокс - прощай ты тоже,

Прощай.

Comment: А старый Опера давно прощай. В новой(12) все пашет. Другое дело, если переход на хромиум не был первоапрельской шуткой, то самый новый Опера тоже заочно прощай. Так и буду, как дурак, на 12й сидеть, пока альтернативы не появится. НО. Это уже холивар, а мессадж был: обновляйте браузер, хотя бы в пределах бренда :)

Comment: в css получается только вращение объекта вокруг своей оси, но мне нужно чтобы нижняя часть была фиксирована, а перемещалась только верхняя часть изображения.

Comment: translate+skew. Первый сдвигает картинку, второй - наклоняет. 
так как skew работает с градусами, а translate с пикселями, вам придется решить несложную задачку, заключающуюся в умножении половины высоты на синус угла поворота. Это и будет необходимое смещение в пикселях.